# How can I make my server continue to receive messages until client closes?

Tags: c, client, server, winsock2

I am writing a simple client and server. I have my client written and I compared it to another server so it works perfectly. I am now trying to replicate the server, and for some reason, when my client sends a message "GET 2", the server reaches the `recv` function and it returns -1. Then it prints on the screen `recv failed` then it tries to do a `shutdown` but it also says `shutdown failed`. Does anyone know why?? I would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFFLEN 1024

const unsigned int LISTENING_PORT = 21001;
const char ipAddress[15] = "127.0.0.1";
SOCKADDR_IN ServerAddr;

int main()
{
    /*Declare and initialize variables*/
    int return_Code = 10;
    char recvBuff[DEFAULT_BUFFLEN] = "";
    char storedQuotes[20][DEFAULT_BUFFLEN];

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET Socket;
    SOCKET AcceptSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN ServerAddr;

    /*Initialize Winsock*/
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    /*Create New Socket*/
    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Server: Socket() failed! Error code: %d.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();

        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }

    /*Specify what address to listen on*/
    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; //IPv4
    ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipAddress); //IP Address
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(LISTENING_PORT); //Port no.

    /*Bind the Socket*/
    if (bind(Socket, (SOCKADDR *)& ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Server: bind() failed! Error code: %d.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();

        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }

    /*Listen on socket for a client*/
    if (listen(Socket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Sever: listen() failed! Error code: %d.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();

        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("Server: Listening on port %d.\n\n", LISTENING_PORT);

    /*Accept a connection from a client*/
    AcceptSocket = accept(Socket, NULL, NULL);
    if (AcceptSocket == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Server: accept() failed! Error code: %d.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();

        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("Server: accept() OK!\n");

    /*Receive and send data*/
    //return_Code = recv(Socket, recvBuff, DEFAULT_BUFFLEN, 0);
    do {

        return_Code = recv(Socket, recvBuff, DEFAULT_BUFFLEN, 0);//THIS LINE RETURNS -1, SO THE MESSAGE IS NEVER PROCESSED.
    //IT GOES TO RECEIVE FAILED THEN SHUTDOWN FAILED.
        if (return_Code > 0)
        {
            if (recvBuff[0] == 'G' && recvBuff[1] == 'E' && recvBuff[2] == 'T')
            {
                printf("GET MESSAGE RECEIVED");
            }
            else if (recvBuff[0] == 'S' && recvBuff[1] == 'E' && recvBuff[2] == 'T')
            {
                printf("SET MESSAGE RECEIVED");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Error: GET and SET NOT RECIEVED");
            }
        }
        else if (return_Code == 0)
            printf("Server: Connection closed!");
        else
            printf("Server: recv() failed! Error code: %d.\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while (return_Code > 0);

    /*Disconnect*/
    if (shutdown(Socket, SD_BOTH) != 0)
        printf("Server: shutdown() failed! Error code: %d.\n", WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("Server: shutdown() OK!\n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Socket` is the socket that's listening for connections. `AcceptSocket` is the connection between your program and the client. You need to call `recv` with `AcceptSocket`, not `Socket`.

Also, `shutdown` doesn't work on listening sockets, only connected ones. The same thing applies - you can `shutdown` `AcceptSocket` but not `Socket`.